Python Union type, but both instead of either
SQLAlchemy has a cool feature where I can write an expression, and depending on the input type, the same expression can build a SQL condition, or evaluate to a value.  I'm trying to do the same in my code, using functions instead of expressions, but I can't figure out how to annotate my functions for mypy to correctly check the types.
The below code works, both assertions pass. However, mypy complains:
example.py:13: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "SQLColumnExpression[Any]"; expected "str | int | bool | date | datetime"  [arg-type]
example.py:14: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str | int | bool | date | datetime"; expected "SQLColumnExpression[Any]"  [arg-type]

As I understand it, the problem is that the var argument can be either of the callables in the Union, but the code expects it to be both.  How would I declare such a type, or better, can I find something somewhere in SQLAlchemy to import ?
from sqlalchemy import SQLColumnExpression, Column, Integer, SQLColumnExpression
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import Union, Callable, Any, overload

Value = Union[str, int, bool, date, datetime]
Operator = Union[
    Callable[[SQLColumnExpression[Any], Value], SQLColumnExpression[Any]],
    Callable[[Value, Value], bool],
]

def some_function(var: Operator, column: SQLColumnExpression[Any], value: Value) -> None:
    assert isinstance(var(column, value), SQLColumnExpression)
    assert isinstance(var(value, value), bool)

@overload
def op(column: SQLColumnExpression[Any], value: Value) -> SQLColumnExpression[Any]: ...

@overload
def op(column: Value, value: Value) -> bool: ...

def op(column, value):  # type: ignore
    print("OP", type(column), type(value))
    return column == 0

Base = declarative_base()
class Model(Base):  # type: ignore
    __tablename__ = "example"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

some_function(op, Model.id, 0)


You need intersection types, which has yet to be a thing in Python's type system.

a | b means "either a or b", not "both a and b". I think you're misinterpreting the error message. The complaint is about the difference between the type of a SQLColumn and the data that column stores; nothing is expecting a type that is simultaneously all the things.

@CharlesDuffy  The "both" interpretation comes from the runtime, not from the annotations.  In the first assert, "var" is one thing, in the second assert it is another.

The first assert is about var(column, value) and the second one about var(value, value). They're two different things.

(That's what the ORM should be doing: When you have a function that refers, to say, X + 1 and X is a SQL expression, then you want to generate a new SQL expression that generates the SQL statement X + 1 for whatever value of X was the input; whereas if X is a value, then you want to just add 1 to it directly in the Python and return the result; so those asserts are checking that both modes of operation do what they should; from the context, some_function is only for boolean operators, but the general logic holds).

What you are looking for is called an intersection type (as opposed to a union type), and Python doesn't have them (yet?).
